# Literals within block quotes ignore overriding syntax selection

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[My recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38699216/622310) starts with an overriding syntax selection:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

however the syntax colouring within the first block quote, which is done by using `>` followed by five spaces, reverts to Stack Overflow's best guess -- Perl in this case.

This shouldn't happen.

Comment: The overriding syntax is supposed to be done **right before** the code block.

Comment: You need `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` if you want to do it globally on the answer.

Comment: @Tunaki: That is my mistake. Thank you. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different ways to override the syntax coloring:

- Globably on the answer with `<!-- language-all: lang-java -->`.
- Per code block with `<!-- language: lang-java -->`. This has precedence over the global override syntax.

This answer is written with `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->`. The following is unformatted:

```
Blob blob
Caused by: NullPointerException
```

just like

> ```
> Blob blob
> Caused by: NullPointerException
> ```

But I can write Java if I want:

```java
public static final String LIFE = "Java";
```

Or (although the syntax highlight for quotes on Meta doesn't render as well as on Main):

> quote XML:
>
> ```xml
> <foo> <bar /> </foo>
> ```

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that I have a short Perl utility that builds the awkward `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` line and puts it on the clipboard for pasting into a SO post. I had misused it so that it generated `<!-- language: lang-none -->` but I overlooked the mistake. All is now as it should be. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The overriding syntax is supposed to be done **right before** the code block.

---

Also you should not be putting code in a quote block -- there is no point to that, that is what the code block is for.

Comment: Disagree, code in quote block is the way to go when you're quoting code you didn't write.

Comment: @Tunaki there is no code like that in the question, that code is all from the answer itself, an example, which belongs in just a code block...

Comment: What Tunaki said, plus warning and error messages are often sensitive to character positions and should be put into a literal

Comment: Sometimes there is more than just code to be quoted. Say for example a text from a documentation. In some situations like that it can make sense to have code in a quote.